# URLSession with Server-Sent Events sometimes return kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork 303

Tags: ios, server-sent-events, urlsession

In our App we request a stream of information with Server-Sent Events.
For this we use the small Library [IKEventSource](https://github.com/inaka/EventSource)
Which under the hood uses `Foundation.URLSession`.

This Information is sent in small JSON Packages For example:

`{"type":"update","data":{"id":"1234","name":"someName","someOtherField":33,"size":"20","someAddress":"Awesome Street 111"}}`

Now this works pretty good for us, but we noticed that sometimes we get the following Error:

`Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=303 "(null)" UserInfo={NSErrorPeerAddressKey=<CFData 0x610000a84510 [0x103ccbe40]>{length = 16, capacity = 16, bytes = 0x100201bbb9131fbd0000000000000000}, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2201, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}`

Which i understand is a `kCFErrorHTTPParseFailure` The String it tries to Parse seems to be just a cut of JSON Package like:

`{"type":"update","data":{"id":"1234","name":"so`

Our current Understanding is, that URLSession is buffering the Data and sometimes it will fill up and the last part will be cut of.
We could reproduce this in the Terminal using `curl http://our.service.com` and see a working example with `curl -N http://our.service.com`

Does somebody know how to add this option to `URLSession`, `URLSessionConfiguration` or `URLSessionTask`. 
Or does anybody have another explanation or Solution (maybe Server side)
With this error our users sometimes miss updates to the Data and we think its the reason for some otherwise unexplainable Feedbacks.

BTW we have the same problem in our corresponding Android app

Comment: Any solutions yet?

Comment: We still have this problem and are planing to change the whole API to get around it.

Comment: Was your server use http/2.0 ?

Comment: Did you solve this error?

Comment: We changed the API as a whole. We did not find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, without using any library, just by using my own implementation with `URLSession`.

I solved it by adding the HTTP header `Accept: text/event-stream`.

```swift
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.setValue("text/event-stream", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
```

Answer (score 0):

Years later, and now with Swift Concurrency, maybe someone will find this helpful.

It seems that the original question regarding the Buffer filling up is an issue. I found that by returning a `AsyncThrowingStream` from the service request that connects to the SSE endpoint, you're able to control the buffer via `AsyncThrowingStream`'s `bufferingPolicy`.

Apple Docs: [AsyncThrowingStream.init(_:bufferingPolicy:_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/asyncthrowingstream/init(_:bufferingpolicy:_:))

The code below is for readability. You could certainly use generics and make something more reusable, but this gets the point across.

Say you had an endpoint that took a POST request with a body, then responded with an event-stream. As [@Guillaume](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1049907/guillaume) mentioned, you'd expect to get `text/event-stream` back rather than typical JSON.

The JSON in the request body might look like this:

```json
{
  "question": "What's the answer?"
}
```

And the response might stream events back as text like this:

```
data: {"answer": "This"}
data: {"answer": "This is"}
data: {"answer": "This is the"}
data: {"answer": "This is the answer."}
```

You need to understand the format of the events coming back from the server in order to properly decode. It should have a JSON string in there somewhere as you'll have to decode something, but it might not be prepended with `data:` . We'll continue to assume that it is for this example.

So here's what the example code would look like to make this request:

```swift
final class Service {
    enum ServiceError: Error {
        case generic
    }

    // 1.
    private var streamTask: Task<Void, Error>?
    private let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/api/events")!
    
    func sendRequest(with question: String) async throws -> AsyncThrowingStream<Response, Error> {
        // 2.
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("text/event-stream; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.setValue("keep-alive", forHTTPHeaderField: "Connection")
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = try JSONEncoder().encode(
            Request(question: question)
        )
        
        // 3.
        let (asyncBytes, response) = try await URLSession.shared.bytes(for: request)
        try Task.checkCancellation()
        
        guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
              (200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode)
        else {
            throw ServiceError.generic
        }
        
        // 4.
        return AsyncThrowingStream(Response.self, bufferingPolicy: .bufferingNewest(3)) { continuation in
            // 5.
            continuation.onTermination = { [weak self] _ in
                self?.streamTask?.cancel()
                self?.streamTask = nil
            }
            
            // 6.
            streamTask = Task {
                // 7.
                for try await line in asyncBytes.lines {
                    try Task.checkCancellation()
                    
                    // 8.
                    guard line.hasPrefix("data: "),
                          let data = line.dropFirst(6).data(using: .utf8)
                    else {
                        // Seems like we got a partial event or one that doesn't start with
                        // `data: `. No big deal. Just continue to the next event in the stream.
                        continue
                    }
                    
                    // 9.
                    do {
                        let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
                        continuation.yield(with: .success(response))
                    } catch {
                        continuation.finish(throwing: error)
                    }
                }
                // 10.
                continuation.finish()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Request: Encodable {
    let question: String
}

struct Response: Decodable {
    let answer: String
}
```

1. We need to hold onto an unstructured Task so we can cancel it later if needed. This will make sense down below.
2. Build out our URLRequest. Nothing too special here.
3. Call this `bytes(for:delegate:)` method. This thing is cool in that it returns `(URLSession.AsyncBytes, URLResponse)`. The `AsyncBytes` part is key. [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/3767350-bytes)
4. Construct our `AsyncThrowingStream` with a defined `bufferingPolicy`. Here, I chose to keep the newest 3 events in the buffer. Do what works or makes sense for you. There is a simpler `AsyncThrowingStream(unfolding:)` we could use but see **GOTCHA** at the bottom after going through these steps for more on that.
5. When the continuation is terminated (i.e. due to cancelation), we should `cancel()` and nil out our `streamTask`. If you're still thinking "What streamTask?" that's step 6.
6. Here's the `streamTask`. We create and hold onto a reference to an unstructured `Task` to do our work. By storing it in the `streamTask` property from step 1, we can cancel it if needed in step 5.
7. Iterate over the `asyncBytes.lines` we got from our URLSession call. See how each `data: {...}` event in our example response above starts on a new line? This will iterate over each of those lines.
8. Check that the content of `line` (remember it's just text, not JSON) starts with `data:`  then strip those characters out and convert it to `Data`. If not, we got something we don't recognize. Just continue on waiting for the next event.
9. Take the `Data` from the previous step and decode it. If successful, `yield` the decoded `Response`. If not, throw and error and we're done. (You could also choose to not be done and continue trying to decode the  next events in the stream).
10. Provided we haven't thrown anything above, once we're done with all the events in the stream, we'll `.finish()`.

**The GOTCHA:**

Some of you may be thinking "You're in an async context! Why use the `AsyncThrowingStream` with the synchronous `build` closure that takes a `continuation` only to wrap an unstructured Task? You've destroyed automatic cancellation! Why not just return `AsyncThrowingStream(unfolding:)`?!?!?!" If you weren't thinking that, or are now thinking "Wait, what?", here it is:

I initially tried just that. Replace everything below `// 4.` with the following and you'll have:

```swift
return AsyncThrowingStream {
    for try await line in asyncBytes.lines {
        try Task.checkCancellation()
        
        guard line.hasPrefix("data: "),
              let data = line.dropFirst(6).data(using: .utf8)
        else {
            // Seems like we got a partial event or one that doesn't start with
            // `data: `. No big deal. Just continue to the next event in the stream.
            continue
        }
        
        do {
            return try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
        } catch {
            throw error
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

My goodness, that is much nicer. Don't need to hold onto some unstructured Task. You get automatic cancellation. Can just return/throw rather than messing with `continuation` stuff. And it's just less code.

**However**, I found that this would just *sometimes* stop mid-stream (often happened for longer responses). I could see in Proxyman that the server was still sending events, but when I put a `print(line)` at the top of the `for try await line in asyncBytes.lines {}` it just stopped printing mid-stream. Even the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/asyncthrowingstream) say "By default, the buffer limit is Int.max, which means it’s unbounded." So either that's not true, or there's some non-buffer related issue happening that the approach using the `continuation` doesn't encounter.

If you go with the `AsyncThrowingStream(unfolding:)` approach, be sure to do plenty of testing.

Would love to hear if anyone has any thoughts why the `continuation` based approach is the only one working.